# Getting internet to a detached garage that has a existing coaxial line

Tags: ethernet, lan, adapter, coaxial

Out door 2 way cable splitter: one line runs into the house where the modem/router is, the other runs into a detached garage. Would a coaxial to LAN converter work in this situation, or do they need to be on the same line?

Comment: If the distance is not too far, you could consider a wifi bridge, as long as you has line of sight, or if its not too far, just wifi repeater.

Comment: That might work but speed is important as well.

Comment: I currently  have a repeater the signal is very weak due to the cinder block .

Comment: Coax isnt really a "thing" in my country but surely you can get a couple of MoCa devices (like https://www.amazon.ca/goCoax-Adapter-Ethernet-Bandwidth-existing/dp/B09RB1QYR9/ref=mp_s_a_1_3?keywords=MoCA+Adapter&qid=1702661676&sr=8-3 ) and convert the coax cable to ethernet?

Comment: I think Maybe my problem is the main line splits ISP in then 1 output to the garage and second output to  the house so there isn't any loop?

Comment: Depending on the coax, it too has speed limitations. You might try a directional "cantenna" at each end of the WiFi path. See https://www.techradar.com/news/computing-components/peripherals/build-the-ultimate-wi-fi-boosting-cantenna-684073 BTW, you can eliminate coax connectors at the PC end by attaching a USB WiFi dongle directly to the can, and using a *short* USB cable to the PC.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a splitter in the coax line before the house modem. The one you have may work.

Then a coax to the detached garage will work just fine. Use outdoor and RG61 cable.

Then you need a new Modem / Router in the Garage. This will all work.

Another way if the distance is not too great (< 100 Meters), you can run outdoor Ethernet (buried) to a switch in the Garage.

Either approach works depending on your needs and what you want as the end result.

Comment: Adding a second modem/router to the garage would be ideal, but if I'm not mistaken (Which I hope I am)  I would have to pay ? I use optimum .

Comment: I actually have a splitter by the modem that I connected my coaxial to lan device and the other device I placed to the coaxial in the garage but I don't seem to get a connection .

Comment: With COAX you need a modem / router (COAX does not pass Ethernet signals).  Or run Ethernet from the house as noted.

Comment: With the coaxial to lan device MoCa you can.

Comment: You are better off long term putting a good solution into place that will last a long time (which has a habit of going by quickly).